# Does [:space:] in a grep command not include newlines and carriage returns?

Tags: grep, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm curently writing a simple Bash script. The idea is to use `grep` to find the lines where a certain pattern is found, within some files. The pattern contains 3 capital letters at the start, followed by 6 digits; so the regex is `[A-Z]{3}[0-9}{6}`.

However, I need to only include the lines where this pattern is not concatenated with other strings, or in other words, if such a pattern is found, it has to be separated from other strings with spaces.

So if the string which matches the pattern is **ABC123456** for example, the line **something ABC123456 something** should be fine, but **somethingABC123456something** should fail.

I've extended my regex using the `[:space:]` character class, like so:

`[[:space:]][A-Z]{3}[0-9}{6}[[:space:]]`

And this seems to work, except for when the string which matches the pattern is the first or last one in the line.

So, the line **something ABC123456 something** will match correctly;

The line **ABC123456 something** won't;

And the line **something ABC123456** won't as well.

I believe this has something to do with `[:space:]` not counting new lines and carriage returns as whitespace characters, even though it should from my understanding. Could anyone spot if I'm doing something wrong here?

Comment: Note that you are _not_ asking about your actual problem `I need to only include the lines where this pattern is not concatenated with other strings`, you are specifically asking about `[:space:]` in Bash.

Comment: Is the string a line from a file or the whole contents of a file? If it's a line, there won't be any leading/trailing newlines.

Comment: `grep` doesn't care which shell you are using, and Bash can't control how `grep` understands its pattern argument.

Comment: `grep` only processes a line at a time. The separators between those lines are never present in its buffer at all; it only evaluates your expression _against each line_, one at a time.

Comment: Personally, I often use `(^|[[:space:]])` and `($|[[:space:]])`.

Comment: (and as was said: this has _nothing whatsoever_ to do with bash; bash doesn't provide grep or control its behavior; your question hinges on grep behavior, not on anything specific to bash)

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I apologize about the question not being about bash in specific, I wasn't sure what else to put it under as it marginally involved both bash and `grep`.
The solution to my particular issue was to use word boundary `\b` in my regex.

Answer (score 0):

A common solution to your problem is to normalize the input so that there *is* a space before and after each word.

```
sed 's/^ //;s/$/ /' file |
grep -oE '[[:space:]][A-Z]{3}[0-9}{6}[[:space:]]'
```

Your question assumes that the newlines are part of what `grep` sees, but that is not true (or at least not how `grep` is commonly implemented). Instead, it reads just the *contents* of each new line into a memory buffer, and then applies the regular expression to that buffer.

A similar but different solution is to specify beginning of line or space, and correspondingly space or end of line:

```
grep -oE '(^|[[:space:]])[A-Z]{3}[0-9}{6}([[:space:]]|$)' file
```

but this might not be entirely portable.

You might want to postprocess the results to trim any spaces from the extracted strings, too; but I have already had to guess several things about what you are *actually* trying to accomplish, so I'll stop here.

(Of course, `sed` can do everything `grep` can do, and then some, so perhaps switch to `sed` or Awk entirely rather than build an elaborate normalization pipeline around `grep`.)

Comment: Thank you. This is useful and I'll keep it in mind for future references. However, the solution to my issue was simply using the word boundary `\b` in my regex, as I stated in a previous comment.